# PostgreSQL: replace plpgsql function by sql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

**Disclaimer** This might be a more theoretical, unpractical question.

I am trying to replace a `plpgsql` function by a `sql` function **without changing the behaviour or result type**. The function looks like this:

```
create function f() returns void as
$$
begin
    perform       some_other_function(my_table.my_column)
    from          my_table;
end;
$$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

This function returns `void`, as I do not care about the results.

As said, I am trying to replace it by a `sql` function. This function is used in a chain of `sql` functions, so it might be performance-wise better to have this function also a `sql` function instead of `plpgsql` (again, see disclaimer).

The following does not work, because now only the first row of `my_table` is processed.

```
create function f() returns void as
$$
    select       some_other_function(my_table.my_column)
    from         my_table;
$$
language sql volatile;
```

Note that function `some_other_function` also returns a void.

Any other clever ways to try out?

Comment: This is difficult to answer if we do not know what functionality is being implemented.

Comment: `some_other_function(id)` creates a new row in some logging table. So, explination of `f()`: for every row in `my_table`, I am using `some_other_function(id)` to create a row somewhere.

Comment: `select count(some_other_function(my_table.my_column))::text::void from my_table;`

Comment: `select exists(some_other_function(my_table.my_column))::text::void from my_table;` Maybe bit faster? Or will PostgreSQL optimize and stop after the first row because the `exists` is already fulfilled?

Comment: I don't know, just try. I think that the `count()` is more reliable because it must to check value for every row.

Comment: Thanks, all good suggestions. Silly question probably, but what makes most sense: this kind of sql queries to avoid the plpgsql function, or keep it simple and keep the plpgsql function as stated in the initial question?

Comment: If you do not plan to call this function thousands times per statement - simplicity is preferable. Also some possible additional system resources for `plpgsql` is vanishingly small compared to read/write operations.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an SQL statement that has to scan the whole table before it can produce the first result row, like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
'SELECT count(CASE
                WHEN some_other_function(my_table.my_column) IS NULL
                THEN 0
             END
       )::text::void
FROM my_table';
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f() RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
'SELECT count(*)::text::void
FROM (
      SELECT some_other_function(my_table.my_column)
      FROM my_table
     ) q';
```

Comment: Thanks, all good suggestions. Silly question probably, but what makes most sense: this kind of `sql` queries to avoid the `plpgsql` function, or keep it simple and keep the `plpgsql` function as stated in the initial question?

Comment: It would be best to continue using PL/pgSQL. A complicated SQL function like these could not be inlined anyway.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.